# SQuirreL sql mmsql microsoft server SSO connection

Tags: sql-server, single-sign-on, squirrel-sql

Just adding this for others help (and my future reference) when setting up squirrel sql on windows domain and having connection hassles.

Assumming the following:

- That "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode" is set in MSSMS (m$
  sql server management studio).  Go  rmc (right mouse click) on the
  server name > properties > Security > Server Authentication

JDBC
Could not get this to work so went jTDS.  Is it worth getting JDBC to work?

jTDS
This needed the domain option added to the url.  ie domain=
I had initially tried using the \ format  ie the typical windows logon (nice furphy:)

Other things that may have helped (but in future tries these last)

- Install latest java jre (had 1.6 and added 1.7)
- Copy ..\jTDS..\SSO\ntlmauth.dll to the jre bin directory.

Comment: Wow, that is one crazy and unreadable title. You should add "rock paper scissors" to the end.

Comment: Have they implemented trick questions much like they do for the review queue?

Comment: Sorry with the title. Is there a "help" tag (as opposed to question)? This is a summation of the search terms.  I checked SO and none existed with SSO included, hence the new thread.

Comment: Is it worth pursuing getting JDBC to work?  Any benefits?